# How to get href attribute using selenium for python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the href attributes from the given HTML code so that i can go inside the link and scrape some data from it.

```css
<div class="cb-col cb-col-67 cb-rank-plyr"> <a class="text-hvr-underline text-bold cb-font-16" href="/profiles/1643/aaron-finch" title="Aaron Finch's Profile">Aaron Finch</a> <div class="cb-font-12 text-gray">AUSTRALIA</div> </div>
```

```css
<div class="cb-col cb-col-67 cb-rank-plyr"> <a class="text-hvr-underline text-bold cb-font-16" href="/profiles/10863/fakhar-zaman" title="Fakhar Zaman's Profile">Fakhar Zaman</a> <div class="cb-font-12 text-gray">PAKISTAN</div> </div>
```

I want to get the attributes of href and save it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to parse out thinks in the HTML such as that href tag.

Here is an article explaining that: https://medium.com/@tracy_blog/regex-and-selenium-2c5a89f23a17

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I would consider using [`get_attribute(name)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) over a regular expression.